# What exactly does this code do

Tags: c

I was going through some c code and came across this syntax:

```
uint16 a;
unsigned char *b;
//b is initilized elsewhere before the next line gets called
((unsigned char*) &a)[0] = b[0];
```

It the last line which I dont get. We typecast the address of uint16 to a unsigned char. Why is this? The address of &a could be larger than 8 bytes. Also whats the [0] on the left of the equals for?

Comment: Your code as posted is meaningless, since b isn't initialized.

Comment: *We typecast the address of uint16 to a unsigned char. Why is this? The address of &a could be larger than 8 bytes* No, it's typecast to `unsigned char *`.

Comment: Its not the complete code . Just snippets. Actually b is passed as a function parameter

Comment: It's a bit ugly, but it sets the first byte of the 16-bit value `a` to the byte that `b` points to. The `0` on the left hand side dereferences the address of `a` (taken as a pointer to an unsigned char`) with an offset of `0`. In this case, as @VaughnCato points out, it's undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're taking the address of `a`, cast it to `unsigned char*` (*not* `unsigned char`), add 0 to it (no op), dereference it and then assign the result of `b[0]` to it. In other words, you're assigning the result of `b[0]` to the first byte of `a`'s in-memory representation.

Since `b` has not been initialized this invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It copies `b[0]` into a part of `a`. Which specific parts depends of:

- Endianness: Little endian or big endian
- the size of each of the types (`uint16` will use 2 bytes, `unsigned char` probably 1).

Note: The "byte" modified in `a` will be always the first byte. Endianness is important because the first byte may be the most significative or the less significative.

Answer (score 0):

This is more common on int types where you want to use a whole word at a time for optimization.  Say you have a large set of strings that you want to compare, but only need to compare the first 4 characters.  Rather than using a slow series of strncmp()s, you can cast each char array to an int and do a straight comparison.  A common use is in web servers for the GET, POST, HEAD... requests.  Depending on your endianness, the cast value may take the form 'TSOP' or 'POST', which is also the case for other types (including your uint16), so the code you are working with *may* not be portable without some #ifdefs

Note: if you just use 'POST' (or 'TSOP') as your comparison you may get warnings about multibyte chars, the workaround (other than turning of the warning) is to use ('P'|'O'<<8|'S'<<16|'T'<<24) or vice versa depending on endianness - it will compile to a const int that can be used in a switch().